# How can I typecast the result of ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask) into a BOOL?

Tags: objective-c

I have had this code that has been broken, and it wasn't only until recently I realized that this isn't valid:

```
  BOOL alwaysDrawGraphic = ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask);
   if( alwaysDrawGraphic )
   {
      NSLog(@"Hey");
   }
```

Because the result of the bitwise operation `&` doesn't return a BOOL.

so I figured I could use `lldb` to `po ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask)`,  but I just get this error:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'NSAlternateKeyMask'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

So then I tried to just `NSLog` the value when I have the Command Key pressed,
`NSLog(@"%lu",  ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask));`

Xcode corrected me and let me know that the value is an `unsigned long`.  But when it logs out, I get this `lu`: `1048576`

If the Command Key it isn't pressed, it prints `0`, as you would expect

So my question is, what is the value `1048576` that I am getting?
And how can I typecast it into a `BOOL` so I can re-use it several times within the same method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the result is 0 or 1 after being masked

```
BOOL alwaysDrawGraphic = ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask) != 0;
```

1048576 is hex 0x00100000 which is the bit position of `NSCommandKeyMask`

Comment: To be clear, `alwaysDrawGraphic` will be `YES` if all of the flags in the `NSAlternateKeyMask` are set in `modifierFlags`.

Comment: There is only one flag (bit). The mask `0x80000` (524288)  ignores all `0` bits except bit 19 which is the `NSAlternateKeyMask` bit.